# Error 'no matching function call' while using map<>.emplace

Tags: c++

I am having trouble using `std::map<>.emplace`.

```
const int NUM_VALUES = 10;
std::map<double, int[NUM_VALUES]> valMap = std::map<double, int[NUM_VALUES]>();

const int LOOP_MAX = 60;
for (int i = 1; i <= LOOP_MAX; ++i) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= LOOP_MAX; ++j) {
    double tempDbl = static_cast<double>(i) / static_cast<double>(j);
    if (valMap.find(tempDbl) == valMap.end()) {
      int tempValues[NUM_VALUES] = {...};
      valMap.emplace(tempDbl, tempValues);  // <-- error here
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
clockCalc.cpp:24:48:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<const double, int [10]>::pair(double&, int [10])’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I've looked at other questions that have suggested using `std::piecewise_construct', but they don't explain why that works and this doesn't.

Comment: You've uncovered C++'s dirty little secret. There is really no such things as arrays, in C++. They're a figment of everyone's imagination, a myth, a mirage. They don't really exist, so it's going to be rather problematic to create a map of something that does not really exist, don't you agree? Perhaps you should try to store maps of `std::array`s, instead, which are real objects, that look very much like arrays and behave like all real objects do, in C++.